# Can I gift a song from the iPhone iTunes app?

Tags: iphone, itunes

Just as the title says: can I gift a song from within the iTunes iPhone app? I searched but couldn't find any option to.

Comment: Its possible in iOS 7.. look at the screenshot here..https://www.dropbox.com/s/8979y51lfs4tun2/Photo%20Nov%2008%2C%201%2057%2019%20PM.png

Comment: @akash that unfortunately applies only to whole albums

Comment: correct. for individual songs, you have to gift it through desktop app..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gifting only works from iTunes on a computer.

Perhaps it could be added if enough people ask to spend money that way.

http://www.apple.com/feedback/

You can also gift from store apps with iOS 6.

Comment: I only now saw the edit to this question, which unfortunately makes it less correct.